# PostGIS type "geometry" doesn't exist when pg_dump copying database to server

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pg-dump

Similar question to many that have already been asked, but I have yet to find a solution.

I'm copying a Postgres db from my local machine to a server using:

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname
```

However, whenever I try to execute this, any tables with PostGIS `geography` columns are skipped and not copied over, and I'm left with the following error:

```
ERROR:  type "<mydb>.geography" does not exist
```

## Attempted solutions:

On this server, I have successfully installed PostGIS and created the relevant extensions:

```
mydb=# select postgis_version();
            postgis_version            
---------------------------------------
 2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
(1 row)
```

Additionally, `geometry` is a recognized data type:

```
mydb=# \dT *.geometry
                     List of data types
 Schema |   Name   |               Description               
--------+----------+-----------------------------------------
 public | geometry | postgis type: Planar spatial data type.
(1 row)
```

My `search_path` includes everything relevant:

```
mydb=# show search_path;
      search_path       
------------------------
 mydb, public, postgis
```

and

```
mydb=# SELECT r.rolname, d.datname, rs.setconfig
FROM   pg_db_role_setting rs
LEFT   JOIN pg_roles      r ON r.oid = rs.setrole
LEFT   JOIN pg_database   d ON d.oid = rs.setdatabase
WHERE  r.rolname = 'mydb' OR d.datname = 'mydb';

 rolname | datname |      setconfig       
---------+---------+----------------------
         | mydb    | {search_path=public}
(1 row)
```

My only guess as to what might be causing this headache is that the superuser on my local machine isn't the same name as the remote superuser. I.e., `localuser` and `remoteuser` don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rest of the answer assumes that the error you quote is the *first* error while restoring the dump. If not, it might be the consequence of an earlier error (e.g., failure to `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`).

If PostGIS is installed on both servers, the message suggests that it is installed in different schemas on both databases.

Examine the result of

```
\dx postgis
```

on both databases to check.

Since PostGIS is not a relocatable extension, you have to drop and re-create it to move it to a different schema.

Comment: Thank you, Laurenz. For future visitors: PostGIS was installed on `<mydb>` schema instead of `public` on my local, while installed in `public` on my remote. To resolve this, I moved PostGIS to `public` on my local: `UPDATE pg_extension SET extrelocatable = TRUE WHERE extname = 'postgis'; ALTER EXTENSION postgis SET SCHEMA public;`

Comment: That will probably have broken your PostGIS installation. In all likelihood there is a reason why the extension is not relocatable.

Comment: Thus far everything is working as expected, thankfully. When I first made the db awhile ago, I initially moved the installation away from `public` to `mydb` (for some reason I can't remember). So essentially I'm moving it back to where it came from... in any case I'm happy so long as my tables are moved away from my local - my computer is on it's last legs and I don't want to lose my data! That is my primary motivation for migrating everything.

Comment: If the catalog update just reverted something you did before, it is probably ok. Next time please don't mess with the catalogs.